# Listeners and Events get error: Too few arguments to function App\Events\User\Created::__construct(),

Tags: laravel, events

I need have two Listeners in same event, and when an user has been created in the system, Lavarel send my an email with the credentials and another to assign roles of users. It's possible have two listeners in same event? Why does the system show me this message?

When I create an user the system show me:

> Too few arguments to function App\Events\User\Created::__construct(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\bwm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents.php on line 205 and exactly 2 expected

This is my Event:

```
class UserCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $user;
    public $password;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user,$password)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

This is my Listener Assign Roles:

```
class AssignRoles
{
    private $request;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Created  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserCreated $event)
    {
        $event->user;
        switch($role = $this->request->role) 
        {

            case $role == 'Asesor':
                $event->user->assignRole('Asesor');                
                $asesoria = Asesoria::orderby('created_at', 'desc')->first();
                $asesoria->user_id = $event->user->id;
                $asesoria->published = true;
                $asesoria->update();
                break;  
            case $role == 'Comprador':
                $event->user->assignRole('Comprador');
                break;
            default:
                $event->user->assignRole('Writer');
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Listener Send Login Credentials:

```
class SendLoginCredentials
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Created  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserCreated $event)
    {
        Mail::to($event->user)->queue(
            new LoginCredentials($event->user, $event->password)
        );

    }
}
```

In my function store of my UsersController I call to dispach:

```
 UserCreated::dispatch($user, $password);
```

In my EventServiceProvider I have this:

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    'App\Events\User\UserCreated' => [
        'App\Listeners\User\AssignRoles',
        'App\Listeners\SendLoginCredentials',
    ],
];
```

Comment: The dispatch method need the event object as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two parameters in your constructor of `UserCreated` class and you are passing only one because you are dispatching it wrong way.

you can do it several ways:

1. `Event::dispatch(new UserCreated($user, $password))`
2. `event(new UserCreated($user, $password))`

Try these. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I had a protected $dispachesEvents in User Model:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = ['created' => 'App\Events\User\Created'];
```

That's why I got the error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Events\User\Created::__construct(), 1 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\bwm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasEvents.php on line 205 and exactly 2 expected

I deleted it, and put the call to the dispacher in my RegisterController.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        //'password' => Hash::make($data['password']), //mutador en User model
        'password' => $data['password'],
        'surname1' => $data['surname1'],
        'surname2' => $data['surname2'],
        'comunidad_id' => $data['cbx_comunidad'],
        'provincia_id' => $data['cbx_provincia'],  
        'municipio_id' => $data['cbx_municipio'],            
    ]);
        //dd($data['password']);
    event(new Created($user,$data['password']));

    return $user;

}
```

As I had a protected $dispatchesEvents in User Model,this it executes before that my call in the RegisterController.